# How did 'praeter-' + 'mitto' compound to generate 'praetermitto'?

Tags: etymology

> [ [Wiktionary :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praetermitto#Latin) ]
>
> Etymology
>
> From [praeter-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/praeter-#Latin) +‎ [mitto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitto#Latin)

The polyfunctionality of *praeter-* and polysemy of *mitto* complicates the determination of the most probable semantic shift (though I can conjecture a few, but have not to keep this post short).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Mitto](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=mitto&filter=CUTF8)* means "to let [something] go". *[Praeter](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=praeter)* means "along [a path], [moving] past/by [a location]". Together, they mean "to let something go along its way, to let something pass by". Metaphorically, if you let something pass by, you get the same meaning as in English: you let it happen, you ignore it, you don't act on it. So the etymology seems to make sense? Or is there something unexpected in it?

Comment: +1. Thanks. About your two last questions: Now they do; I could not determine which meanings were apt for 'mitto' and 'praeter'.

Comment: @LePressentiment: Cool, great!